# Can we let users with privileges on one site have them on another?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, review, privileges

I have almost 4k reputation on Arqade. On Stack Overflow, I have to suggest edits and can't hit the close button. But I want to help with the close queue, which is at 62k at the time of this writing.

While I realize that people may be inexperienced with the system, I think I am experienced enough. If I want to edit something, I have to let it sit in the queue and get robo-reviewed. Yes, I know more about gaming than about coding. But I think I would know if this question is a duplicate of that, and if this question is off topic.

So, my request is that we should have the same privledges on every site, based on the site that we have the most reputation in. I am **not** asking that all the reputation be merged.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You do get them. With the association bonus.

That takes you to 101 rep on **any site on the network** (once you clear 200 on one). That's 9 privileges.

Now, I appreciate that you want more, but without active participation on a specific site, it is not clear that someone does have the know how (would you trust someone with +100k rep on Cooking to go onto the Stack Overflow close queue?).

Comment: That doesn't really let me help With the review queue.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ - no, it doesn't. But it does let you participate more than with just 1 rep (you can comment, for example).

Comment: But I think I ought to know if something is off topic or if its a duplicate of something else.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ `off topic` is a good example for things  which are very different on the sites

Comment: @jeffreylin_ - sure. But how do _we_ know _you_ know if you don't participate enough?

Answer (score 22):

Each site has their own community, their own culture.

The reason for closing a question on one site is completely different than another.

Proper post formatting can change from site to site.

You must acquire reputation on that site to prove you understand that sites culture.

Comment: Good point about different attitude towards what is or is not acceptable in different communities.

Answer (score 3):

Reputation represents more than a willingness to help. It is a rough measure of how well a particular community trusts a user. That trust is gained by *proving* oneself useful, usually by asking good questions or posting good answers.

In a different community, that reputation means little or nothing. You may be willing to help, but you have to prove to the community that you are *able* to help; the way to do that is to gain reputation.

There are potential dangers in allowing untrusted users access to moderation tools. As you mentioned, robo-reviewers are a problem now. Would the situation be improved if we added unknowledgeable reviewers to the mix as well? I suspect not.